# angularjs filter on nested objects

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am quite new with angularjs so I am not sure if what I am trying to do is the right way. Basically I want to display in my page a nested object, and a filter, this way the user can easily type keywords on an input and the content get filtered, to only display the recods that get found by the filter

However I notice that the filter gets the whole parent object and i was expecting only display the record, so with the following code, if i search for Japan it will display Sydney, Melbourne and los angeles.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp',['ngSanitize']);
    demoApp.controller('simpleC',['$scope', function ($scope){
        $scope.info = [
        {name: 'Documents',links:  [
                {linkname:'title1',linknamesublink:[
                        {namesublink:'document 1', description: 'Sydney'},
                        {namesublink:'document 2', description: 'Tokyo <b>Japan</b>'}
                        ]},
                {linkname:'title2',linknamesublink:[
                        {namesublink:'document 3', description: 'Melbourne'},
                        {namesublink:'document 4', description: 'Los Angeles'}
                        ]}
                ]},
        {name: 'Video',links:  [
                {linkname:'title1',linknamesublink:[
                        {namesublink:'video 1', description: 'California'},
                        {namesublink:'video 2', description: 'San Francisco <b> USA</b>'}
                        ]},
                {linkname:'title2',linknamesublink:[
                        {namesublink:'video 3', description: 'South America'},
                        {namesublink:'video 4', description: 'Northern <b>Europe</b>'}
                        ]},
                {linkname:'title3',linknamesublink:[
                        {namesublink:'video name 5', description: 'Africa'},
                        {namesublink:'video name 6', description: 'Bangkok <b>Thailand</b>'}
                        ]}
                ]},
        ];
    }]);
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="demoApp">
    <br /><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" >           
    <div ng-controller="simpleC">
        <div ng-repeat="i in info | filter:search" >
            {{i.name}}  : 
            <div ng-repeat="link in i.links">
                {{link.linkname}}
                    <div ng-repeat="sublink in link.linknamesublink">
                            {{sublink.namesublink}}: <!--{{sublink.description}}-->
                            <span ng-bind-html="sublink.description"></span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like autocomplete? You can consider using `typeahaed` directive explained on this link: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: For the person who down vote this question (if ever come back to read it), can you please provide a reason for down voting and if it is replicate question or too simple question for you please provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this example

http://www.whatibroke.com/?p=857

You can use **filter** in ng-repeat to filter items by property or write a filter yourself.

The author want to filter postcode property by the value of searc_postcode. So, he wrote //filter {postcode : search_postcode} //

Ps. Sorry, I misinterpret your question.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, I have try that but it doesnt work, not sure if it is because i am searching for a nested object?

Comment: @user668027 Yes, it's doesn't work with nested properties. Maybe you should create a custom filter yourself. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 0):

Write your own filter function. This way, you have total control over what is returned. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

```
module.filter('searchfilter', function() {
  return function(searchexpr) {
   var filteredList = ['my', 'filtered', 'result'];//implement yourself
   return filteredList;   
  }; 
});
```

and use `searchfilter` instead of `filter` in your markup.

Or, try to use a filter function as described here: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html (as far as I can tell, you didn't define a search function, i.e. the first agument for the filter expression).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand those examples as it seems they are hardcoding what they want to filter?

Comment: Indeed, the example hardcodes the return value (the little comment gives a hint :-)). You have to roll your own filter function (i.e. loop through your list and filter out required items). This isn't too hard and has nothing to do with angular per se.

Comment: As per my second suggestion ("Or, ...") you could define a filter function that decides whether or not to accept the value (the `search` argument in your example is *not* a function), but that won't work for your data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Modified :

If you want to filter the objects based on any field(say "name"), you can use the below format

```
<div ng-repeat="i in info" ng-if="search==i.name">
```

Comment: Hi,well I tough that the filter will be the second line on the html: <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" >

Comment: Hi @user668027, based on which field in the object "info" you want to filter the result

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you need to filter it based on any other field, please update. I will try to help

Comment: Thank you Pavi, meanly on description, that is within the object linknamesublink, that is within the object links. however or ideally will also filter on the other fields. as it is nested your option will be something like: ng-if="search==i.links.linknamesublink.description" ?

Comment: @user668027 : You won't be able to directly access i.links.linknamesublink as "links" is an array

Comment: Otherwise, you have to move the ng-if to the inner ng-repeats. Then what you need to check is the display of the {{i.name}} outside the condition. That is, {{i.name}} will be always there if you move the condition to inner ng-repeats and might need an extra condition to handle the same